# How to make sure that a memory card is compatible to my mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory

I want to upgrade my RAM from 4g to 8g.

my mac specs are:

[image]

[image]

I need 2 4g memory cards, and this is a specific card I saw in a store that should be working, but no one gives a guarantee it will work on mac...they say it works on laptops, but they can't guarantee its working for mac...

This is the card model: `G.Skill 1x4GB DDR3 1600Mhz SODIMM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com)'s online configurator rather than the vague specs in a shop window.

That way you have a guarantee it will work.

[Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/devices?DevicesType=Desktop) & [Corsair](http://www.corsair.com/en/memory-finder) have the same kind of thing, but Crucial gives you the option of downloading an app to do all the work for you.